# rails way to calculate subtotal and total

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sum, subtotal

Context: I have 2 models Order and Item.

I want to calculate Item subtotal based on item.quantity * item.price
For now this is done in the view (but not the appropriate place).

```
<%= number_to_currency(item.quantity * item.price) %>
```

I also need to calculate the Order total but I'm stuck. I don't have any column for that.
What's the best approach? Use the model? Helper or Observer?

For now I managed to have subtotal working through Order helper

```
def item_subtotal(item)
  item_subtotal = item.quantity * item.price
end
```

**Working Solution:**

Item model

```
def subtotal
  price * quantity
end
```

In View render `<%= item.subtotal %>`

Order model

```
def total_price
  total_price = items.inject(0) { |sum, p| sum + p.subtotal }
end
```

Order#show view render `<%= number_to_currency(@order.total_price) %>`

Answer (score 7):

On your Item model you could add a subtotal method:

```
def subtotal
  quantity * price
end
```

Assuming that you're Order model as a has_many relationship with Item you could `map` the collection to get a list of prices on the Order model:

```
def subtotals
  items.map do |i| i.subtotal end
end
```

Because you're running in a Rails environment you can use the activesupport `sum` method to get the total on an Order model:

```
def total
  subtotals.sum
end
```

Or if you prefer putting it all together:

```
def total
  items.map do |i| i.subtotal end.sum
end
```

Then you can use the subtotal on Item and total on Order in your views.

Edit: The view could look like this:

```
<% for item in @order.items %> <%= item.price %><br/><% end %>
<%= @order.total %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a functionality of the model (you want to calculate something of the item that is self-referential), the more appropriate location is the model itself, so that you can easily use

```
item.subtotal
```

Comment: which model: order or item? How does it know that subtotal equals price * quantity? What about total?

Comment: subtotal should be defined inside `Item` model while the grand total should be calculated inside `Order` total by selecting all the items and calculating their subtotal.

Comment: Can you please write an example for total and especially how to render in the view. thanks. The order#show view goes like this `<% for item in @order.items %> <%= item.price %>`

Answer (score 0):

You can Show the item_subtotal by using

and for grand total you can calculate it by

total_price = @order.items.to_a.sum { |item| total = item.product.price*item.quantity }

I think this will work for you.